# I want to split on a comma in a column where the values are seperated by commas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```py
data = {'X':['A, B, C'], 'Y':[['apple, pear, berries'], ['milk, butter, eggs'], ['apple, milk, bread']]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to loop through column "Y" to split on the "," and save to an empty list that will only store the unique values.

I have tried:

```
list = data['Y'].tolist()
new_list = set(list)
```

But it does not return what I am looking for.

any help would be much appreciated.

The expected output would look like a list that appears:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'berries', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'bread']
```

---

Comment: I think you have a missing `]` before `}`,

Comment: are apples, pear, berries, .. strings?

Comment: you are right. I will fix that

Comment: yes they are strings.

Comment: I am not sure what is the output you are looking for, so if you can provide an example that would be great to clarify this question.

Comment: I have clarified the question, thanks for the input

Comment: Split on the commas? those are syntactic commas, not part of the string(s)...

Comment: @wjandrea that was my bad, I fixed the syntax.

Comment: ... and changed the question completely.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre]

Comment: the provided dataframe isnt even valid..

Answer (score 3):

Try this one-line code, without Pandas:

```
data = {'X':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Y':[['apple', 'pear', 'berries'], ['milk', 'butter', 'eggs'], ['apple', 'milk', 'bread']]}

list(set(sum(data['Y'], [])))
# output: ['apple', 'milk', 'bread', 'pear', 'eggs', 'butter', 'berries']
```

You can compare my solution with those based on pandas:

#### My solution:

```
%%timeit
list(set(sum(data['Y'], [])))
# 805 ns ± 4.84 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### [@lmiguelvargasf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57965216/9302488)'s pandas solution:

```
# Without df creation
%%timeit
#df = pd.DataFrame(data)
l = df['Y'].values.tolist() # this will have the same as data['Y']
new_list = list(set(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)))
# 5.75 µs ± 220 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# With df creation
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
l = df['Y'].values.tolist() # this will have the same as data['Y']
new_list = list(set(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)))
# 658 µs ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As you can see from the previous results my solution seems to be much more efficient than the one based on pandas. **Simple is better** :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have may flaws in your logic. First, do not use `list` as a variable name since this is a Python's built-in function.

Second, I think you do not have clear that `data` is a dictionary, so `data['Y']` will give you a list of list. Thus, you are not able to apply methods that are used with a Dataframe.

Third, you can obtain your expected output using the [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function

I believe you want to convert `data` into a dataframe, so use the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data = {'X':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Y':[['apple', 'pear', 'berries'], ['milk', 'butter', 'eggs'], ['apple', 'milk', 'bread']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
l = df['Y'].values.tolist() # this will have the same as data['Y']
new_list = list(set(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)))
```

You can save some time by not converting to a data frame and directly applying the reduce function to `data['Y']`:

```py
new_list = list(set(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, data['Y'])))
```

**Output**

```py
['apple', 'berries', 'bread', 'butter', 'eggs', 'milk', 'pear']
```